# JOIN with QueryDSL's BooleanBuilder

Tags: java, querydsl

I have this table `t_tarif_quantite` that has two different foreign key columns referencing to the same table (`t_facturation_element`).

```
alter table t_tarif_quantite 
    add constraint FKt4c9hn6gcm5gb5ext52dvi4pf 
    foreign key (fk_facturation_element_id) 
    references t_facturation_element;

alter table t_tarif_quantite 
    add constraint FKsryv7qxxo16cx1qkro5qea7wh 
    foreign key (fk_facture_individuelle_element_id) 
    references t_facturation_element;
```

I am using the `BooleanBuilder` from `QueryDSL` as following in my Java file:

```
BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
predicate.and(qUsager.elementsFacturation.any().quantiteParTarifs
    .any().tarif.id
    .in(listTarifs));
```

My problem is at this part:

```
elementsFacturation.any().quantiteParTarifs.any()
```

It creates an `INNER JOIN` using the wrong foreign key (in my case the wrong foreign key is `fk_facture_individuelle_element_id`) as following:

```
FROM
    s_52_bill.t_facturation_element elementsfa3_ 
INNER JOIN
    s_52_bill.t_tarif_quantite quantitepa4_ 
        ON elementsfa3_.id=quantitepa4_.fk_facture_individuelle_element_id
```

Is it possible to specify on which foreign key to do the `INNER JOIN`? How can I do that?